# Number of unique prime factors in Matrix Set theory considerations and congruence relations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, number-theory

Defining a two variable arithmetic function:

$$ \delta (i,j)=
\cases{1&$i=j$\cr 0&$i\neq j$\cr}
$$

$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(0.0)$$

Then generating the square matrices that result from defining that function in terms of the matrix indices:

$$A_{{N}}=\Biggl[ \delta \Biggl(\frac{i}{j},\Biggl\lfloor \frac{i}{j}\Biggr\rfloor\Biggr)\Biggr]_{{N}}$$

$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(0.1)$$

The following conditions appear to be held, and the view that is currently held that an inductive proof that utilizes identity (1.4) for the first two and fourth, (the first two implying the third) would be sufficient, however anything to the contrary would be appreciated:

($I_N$ is the $N^{th}$ order square identity matrix)

$$(A_{{N}}-{\it I}_{{N}})\cdot ({A_{{N}}}^{-1}-{\it I}_{{N}})=2\,{\it 
I}_{{N}}-{A_{{N}}}^{-1}-A_{{N}}
$$
$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(1.0)$$

$$(A_{{N}}+{\it I}_{{N}})\cdot( {A_{{N}}}^{-1}+{\it I}_{{N}})-2\,{\it 
I}_{{N}}={A_{{N}}}^{-1}+A_{{N}}$$
$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(1.1)$$

$$(A_{{N}}-{\it I}_{{N}})\cdot ({A_{{N}}}^{-1}-{\it I}_{{N}})+(A_{{N}}+{\it I}_{{N}})\cdot( {A_{{N}}}^{-1}+{\it I}_{{N}})-4\,{\it 
I}_{{N}}=0$$
$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(1.2)$$

$$\det(A_N)=1 \quad \forall N \in \mathbb N$$

$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(1.3)$$

$$\left\lfloor {\frac {k}{n}}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor {\frac {k-1}{n}}
\right\rfloor=\delta \left( {\frac {n}{k}},\left\lfloor {\frac {n}{k}}
\right\rfloor \right)$$

$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(1.4)$$

But the real lacking of substance is in the following number theory based analysis of $A_N$:

$$B_{{N}}=(A_{{N}}+{A_{{N}}}^{-1})-2\,{\it 
I}_{{N}}=[b_{ij}]_N$$

$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(2.0)$$

$$b_{ij}=\cases{\alpha_{j}&$i=1$\cr \beta_j&$i=2$\cr 0*&$2 \lt i \leq N$\cr}$$

*This is quite likely to be false for higher order $N$ beyond current computational capacity, but still the restriction to the set ${\{0,1,2}\}$ is expected to be held, so the real primary component of this question lies in what the piecewise form for $b_{ij}$ truly is rather than the approximation made here. If indeed $b_{ij}$ is $0$ for all $i \gt 2$, then of course that proof becomes my question.

$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(2.1)$$

$$\alpha_j=\cases{0&$\omega(j)=1 \,\lor\,\omega(j)>2 $\cr 1&$\exists \,k \gt 1:j^{\frac{1}{k}} \in \mathbb N$\cr 2&$\omega(j)=2$\cr}$$

$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(2.2)$$

The above conditions can be restated as follows:

for $j$ that are either prime or square free numbers that are not semiprimes, $\alpha_j$ will be $0$.

for $j$ that are not square-free,$\alpha_j$ will be $1$.

for $j$ that are semi-primes,$\alpha_j$ will be $2$.

The three conditions in (2.2) forming an equivalence relation on $\mathbb N$ give *some* substance to the approach:
$${\{j \in \mathbb N:\omega(j)=1 \,\lor\,\omega(j)>2}\}\cup{\{j \in \mathbb N:\exists \,k \gt 1:j^{\frac{1}{k}} \in \mathbb N}\}\cup{\{j \in \mathbb N:\omega(j)=2}\}=\mathbb N$$
$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(2.3)$$

And the values of $\beta_j$ being restricted to the same as alpha does hint at some union of three disjoint subsets of $\mathbb N$ in the same manner, but I have not yet been able to find conditions $R_1$ & $R_2$

$$\beta_j=\cases{0&$\omega(j)=1 \lor R_1(\beta_j)$\cr 1&$R_2(\beta_j)$\cr 2&$\tau(j) \in {\{6,8}\}$\cr}$$

$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(2.4)$$

$\tau(k)$ is the total number of divisors of $k$

One elementary number theoretic function that depends on $\omega(n)$ and also has the property of being a three tier piecewise function is the mobius function, and representing this function solely in terms of $\omega(n)$ shows a strong algebraic similarity to $\text{(0.1)}$:

$$\mu(n)=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\delta \left( {n}^{ \frac{1}{k+1}},
\left\lfloor {n}^{ \frac{1}{k+1}}\right\rfloor \right) 
 \left( \delta \left(\omega \left( n \right)-2\left\lfloor \frac{\omega \left( n \right) }{2}
\right\rfloor,0 \right) -\delta \left(\omega \left( n \right)-2\left\lfloor \frac{\omega \left( n \right) }{2}
\right\rfloor,1 \right)  \right)$$

$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(3.0)$$

Comment: Equation (0.1) is simply saying that the $i,j$ entry equals $1$ if $j$ divides $i$ and $0$ otherwise. The notation in this post can therefore be simplified considerably. I imagine that matrix has been studied already at some point.

Comment: Well yes the choice of notation is a trade off of simplification in exchange for being able "see" binary relations in an algebraic sense. I also imagine it has been studied at some point.

Comment: @GregMartin sorry please feel free to make alterations as you see fit to the notation used, I have a tendency to be stubborn in that regard and attempt a pass of a trivial reason why the notation I choose was important